# Insert multiple rows using one SQL statement based on range of months selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do we approach this? There's a date range from January to December, so the range is 12.

It will just copy value2 and value3.

How will we use the value of range from January to December in SQL SERVER for it to create 12 rows?

I understand that this works manually.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES
(value1, value2, value3, ...),
(value2, value2, value3, ...),
(value3, value2, value3, ...),
(value4, value2, value3, ...),
(value5, value2, value3, ...),
(value6, value2, value3, ...),
(value7, value2, value3, ...),
(value8, value2, value3, ...),
(value9, value2, value3, ...),
(value10, value2, value3, ...),
(value11, value2, value3, ...),
(value12, value2, value3, ...);
```

And so on,

Is there a way for us to do this automatically, assuming that the loop should be 12 rows? Similar to this screenshot as a result?

[image: pic1]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for those expected results? If *sounds* like you just need to create a Cartesian product with a `VALUES` clause of `(1),(2),(3)...(12)`

Comment: @Larnu, the screenshot I provided, it's the same as what I'm testing in my database right now. What I want to do is to loop the adding of data. Assuming that my ````Month```` value is 12. Instead of adding the ````Month```` value into database, I will use it as a loop to create 12 rows instead.

Comment: So if your screenshot is your sample data, what are your expected results? We need both here.

Comment: @Larnu, actually, that is my expected result. Is there a way to do that without doing it manually? Like doing ````(value1, value2, value3, ...),```` to ````(value12, value2, value3, ...),````

Comment: Use a recursive cte.

Comment: So I refer to my first comment *"Can you provide some sample data for those expected results?"* You've now said that screenshot is your sample data **and** expected results, which is it? It can't be both. We appear to be stuck in a loop here (which isn't something you want to use for your SQL by the way).

Comment: @Larnu, apologies for the confusion, the data is only ````Value2=100```` and ````Value3=100```` What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the screenshot. So basically my sample data is ````Value1=12````, ````Value2=100```` and ````Value3=200````

Comment: So it's expected results it again..? It can't be both. This is why you think you need a loop; you're stuck on one yourself. Loops should be avoided as much as possible in an RDBMS, and only used when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CTE you can achieve that:

```
WITH Calendar AS (
    SELECT CAST('20190101' AS DATE) AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date])
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]) <  CAST('20200101' AS DATE)
)

SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, [date]) AS [Month], 100 AS [Data 1], 200 AS [Data 2] 
FROM Calendar
```

Please find the working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d53db39e15b25717dbd942675b2ff04)

Including the `INSERT` statement and the actual implementation as:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE ([Month] INT, [Data 1] INT, [Data 2] INT);

WITH Calendar AS (
    SELECT CAST('20190101' AS DATE) AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date])
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]) <  CAST('20200101' AS DATE)
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable ([Month], [Data 1], [Data 2])
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, [date]) AS [Month], 100 AS [Data 1], 200 AS [Data 2] 
FROM Calendar

SELECT * FROM @TestTable
```

Comment: This is easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @pjustindaryll You're Welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

If @Arulkumar (guess) is correct, then there seems little point for an rCTe for such a small data set:

```
SELECT CalendarMonth,
       100 AS Data1,
       200 AS Data2
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(CalendarMonth);
```

If you need a much larger range, I prefer a Tally table to an rCTE (which is recursive as the name suggests):

```
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N n4), --10,000 rows
Calendar AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, T.I-1,'19000101') AS MonthDate
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT MonthDate,
       100 AS Data1,
       200 AS Data2
FROM Calendar;
```

Comment: The problem is the data range can be from 2-5 years. so that's a lot of months to be looped.

Comment: But this isn't a loop, that's the point. Loops are bad in SQL Server.

Comment: The above can actually create 10,000 months of rows without a single loop, @pjustindaryll